# how to show the map in asp.net between to destinations?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, google-maps

If i have a aspx webform in my webform i have two textboxes

From Destination = Textbox1.text
To Destination = textbox2.text

on page load event...i want the gmap will display according to the cities entered in textbox1 and textbox2 and display both cities in map and distances between them ...

how to do it using vb.net ,,,

can any body have an idea to do that ...using vb.net / visualstudio20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small search in google will fetch you lot of articles on doing this. Here is one from [Fryan](http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/04/vbnet-using-google-maps-on-your.html) explaining how to do in Vb.net

Another one to [create maps control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/LatLaysFlat-Part1.aspx)